# Results not being printed

Tags: woocommerce-offtopic

I am trying to run the following code, which i got from the [site](http://biostall.com/how-to-display-woocommerce-featureds-product-without-a-shortcode) but i don't see any output.When i do `print_r($product)` only then i get array back.

```
$args = array(  
    'post_type' => 'product',   
    'posts_per_page' => 4  
);  
$featured_query = new WP_Query( $args );      
if ($featured_query->have_posts()) :   
    while ($featured_query->have_posts()) :   
        $featured_query->the_post();  
        $product = get_product( $featured_query->post->ID );  
        echo $product;
    endwhile;     
endif;
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're `_doing_it_wrong`, as `$product` is an object.

I'm pretty sure you want something like this:

```
$args = array(
    'post_type' => 'product',
    'posts_per_page' => 4,
);
$featured_query = new WP_Query($args);

if ($featured_query->have_posts()) {
    while ($featured_query->have_posts()) {
        $featured_query->the_post();
        ?>
        <h1 class="post-title"><?php the_title(); ?></h1>
        <div class="post-content"><?php the_content(); ?></div>
        <?php
    }
    wp_reset_postdata();
}
```

Comment: appreciate it, but not sure what you mean by `post` is an object.? where was the code wrong.?

Comment: You cannot just do `echo $post;` while `$post` is an object. What would you expect from _printing an object_?